# when browser back button is clicked, get previous search results React

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

Working on an old application that is built in class based components. Basically there is a search bar and as you type the search is filtered, you can then click on one of the options of what was filtered.

After clicking on one of the options I need to be able to click the back browser button and have the previous search show up. Here is what the component looks like.

```js
class Carriers extends React.Component {

async componentDidMount() {
    try {
      await modelApp.actions.setLoading(true)
      await modelCarrier.actions.getList()
      await modelApp.actions.setLoading(false)
    } catch (e) {
      await modelApp.actions.setLoading(false)
      await modelApp.actions.setError(e)
    }
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      search: '',
      searchShow: false
    }
  }

  filterSearch = (list) => {
    if (!list) return []
    const { search } = this.state
    const searchLower = search.toLowerCase()
    return list.filter((item) => item.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchLower))
  }

  handleChange = (name, value) => {
    const state = {
      ...this.state.rec,
      [name]: value,
    }
    this.setState(state)
  }

  handleSearchShow = () => {
    this.setState({
      searchShow: true
    })
  }

  handleSearchClose = () => {
    this.setState({
      search: '',
      searchShow: false
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { history, listActive } = this.props,
      { search, searchShow } = this.state

    const linkAdd = '/carriers/add'

    return (
      <div className="my-3">
        <div className="container section-container">

          <div className="row justify-content-center">
            <div className="col-md-8">
              {searchShow ? (
                <h3 className="app-title-bar d-flex align-items-center">
                  <i className="far fa-search"></i>
                  <input
                    autoFocus
                    className="flex-grow-1 form-control mx-3"
                    onChange={e => onFieldChange(e, this.handleChange)}
                    name="search"
                    placeholder="search for a carrier"
                    type="text"
                    value={search}
                  />
                  <span onClick={this.handleSearchClose} className="float-right mr-3 hover-highlight">
                    <i className="far fa-times"></i>
                  </span>
                </h3>
              ) : (
                <h3 className="app-title-bar">
                  Carriers
                  <Link to={linkAdd} className="float-right hover-highlight">
                    <i className="far fa-plus-square"></i>
                  </Link>
                  <span onClick={this.handleSearchShow} className="float-right mr-3 hover-highlight">
                    <i className="far fa-search"></i>
                  </span>
                </h3>
              )}
              <CarrierList history={history} list={this.filterSearch(listActive)} search={search} />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

If anyone could help me out that would be great, class based stuff is confusing to me and just need a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: Where are you stuck? Telling us your goal and providing code is great, but what exactly is currently causing you a problem?

Comment: I guess I am unsure on how to get the previous state of search, and have that run again when the back button in the browser is clicked.